# Rundeck Job Notification Webhook Certificate Issue

Tags: rundeck

I have a job that Sends Notification On success or On failure. It uses the Webhook option. The webhook is a Rundeck API that executes a job.
[Here is my notification setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IQjg.png)

I've check on the rundeck.log. It has the following error:

```
ERROR services.NotificationService [quartzScheduler_Worker-6] - Notification failed [onsuccess,succeeded,238621]; URL https://client-dns/api/33/job/cd3b3a1b-90c9-4c99-bf29-46c5aad1b4ff/run?authtoken=6XpW50hvZoPUTtlwucKGJ7ERKOxeJCTR&option.rd_exec_id=238621: Unable to POST notification after 1 tries: success for execution 238621 (succeeded): Error making request: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

How can I fix this issue? I have already a certificate but how can I tell rundeck to use it. Thank in advance to those who'll help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [add](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36427118/10426011) the webhook service certificate to the Java cacert to make recognizable by Rundeck. Alternatively, if you are using [Rundeck over SSL](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/ssl.html#configuring-ssl), you can add that certificate to Rundeck `truststore` file in the following way:

1. Stop the Rundeck Service.
2. Extract the service certificate:

`echo -n | openssl s_client -connect your_service_host:your_service_port > cert.out`

3. Add it to your Rundeck truststore file:

`keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -file certs.out -alias my_service -keystore your/path/to/rundeck/truststore`

4. Start Rundeck service.

Comment: Hi, I'm using Rundeck Over SSL. I've already imported the cert to my trust store. I've used this command from the guide I'm following: "keytool -import -alias ca -file /etc/rundeck/ssl/lab-ca-der.cer -keystore /etc/rundeck/ssl/ca -storepass password". Does the naming of the truststore important? Because in the guide I've been following they renamed it to ca and I've done that too.

Comment: I have fixed the issue already. I did the first one which is imported my certificate in java cacerts and now the webhook is working.